# No surround sound over HDMI

Tags: drivers, hdmi, surround-sound

I have my Pioneer receiver hooked up to my AMD HD4600 which supports audio output over HDMI. I used to work fine, however, after a recent driver update, it will only output stereo sound. It used to output 5.1 surround sound perfectly.

Windows does not seem to recognize the device as capable of 5.1.

[image]

[image]

In the past, 5.1 was given as an option in the configuration window, like this: [image]

I can not get it to properly recognize the capabilities of the device. I have tried uninstalling the relevant audio device in device manager, and I have also completely removed and reinstalled the display driver.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: *"after a recent driver update"* - That's one of the pitfalls of updating drivers/software w/o the purpose of fixing a specific issue.  The technical term is *regression*, the reappearance of a previously fixed bug or the loss of a feature.  If the driver(s) cannot be *rolled back*, then what I've done is either reinstall the whole OS and inhibit the driver update(s), or live with it & just wait for another driver update with the fix.  I've been burned several times by Nvidia "updates", as recnetly as 2 weeks ago in Win8.

Comment: I suppose I can live with it. It just bothers me not using everything to it's full potential.

Comment: In the Any suggestions catagory, many of the methods for multi channel seperations are via "licenced" technologies DTS THX Dolby etc.  In some driver updates I get for my audio card, only the original disk holds the "licenced" technologies. The publicly releaced driver updates did not contain them. I assume that we are paying for these technologies when purchacing a product with them in it, and they have rules for distributions.

Comment: That or it is just some "filter" item that got broken along the way, some "codec" thing that changed or 101 other things that can happen.

Comment: I haven't been using the driver from the original disk for quite some time now, but good suggestion.